# Sprinv MVC No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I just started learning Spring MVC, and i've been following along with this youtube series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkRZfxznaOo&index=1&list=PLsyeobzWxl7rjSO6xX00UWmVhL90i-cOk

I'm just trying to create a simple project, in order to see if the I can get the mapping to the Controller correct. Right now, the goal is to just have the controller called and print out to the console one word, when the following URL is called: localhost:8080/Leonardo/login

However, I keep receiving the following error: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Leonardo/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'leonardo'

I've been searching other questions / answers on StackOverflow, and a common resolution is to add "/" in "url-pattern" in my web.xml file, however that is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated. I've just done the bare minimum that was done in the youtube series, and it works fine in that video, but is not working for me.

Project Structure:

[image]

Web.xml

```
 <web-app>
      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

      <servlet>
           <servlet-name>leonardo</servlet-name>
           <servletclass>
                 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
           </servlet-class>
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>leonardo</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

leonardo-servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd 
   ">

        <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
        <ctx:component-scan base-
         package="org.htech.leonardo.controllers"></ctx:component-scan>
   </beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
 package org.htech.leonardo.controllers;

 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

 @Controller
 public class HomeController {

     @RequestMapping("/login")
     public void login() {
          System.out.print("HAHAHAH");
     }
 }
```

Comment: If you put your Java source files under src/main/resources instead of src/main/java, they won't even be compiled.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much, really appreciate it

Comment: Also be aware that that tutorial is apparently years out of date--these days, just use Spring Boot and don't worry about any XML files, containers, or complicated configuration.

Answer (score 2):

At first make sure that your root URL is `localhost:8080/Leonardo/`.
How can you know that? Run your project and check what is URL displayed on your browser.
After that try hitting the URL `{your_root_url}/login` instead of `localhost:8080/Leonardo/login`.
Often the root URL is simply `localhost:8080/`. 
So you can try hitting `localhost:8080/login` instead of `localhost:8080/Leonardo/login`

Answer (score 0):

The `login` method in the controller map to your `{base url}/login`.  When you run your application, the first url that show up in the browser is your base url.